# Greedy Motif Search [ Reasoning ]

Tags: phylogenetics, motifs

I was able to execute the algorithm correctly. But I'm still trying to get a hold of the result I'm achieving.

This is the algorithm I'm trying to understand -

http://rosalind.info/problems/ba2d/

If anyone can, can anybody give a description on why we are using the first DNA's k-mer, as the initial Motif to get a profile, which is further is used on a different DNA string to get its most probable pattern.

How this helps, How they are dependent?

And why a lower score between those Motifs, help us to identify the BestMotifs?

I have gone through the below question, but the perspective is different, it seems to be the same course. -

[Greedy Motif Search Using Probability Matrices](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/2390/greedy-motif-search-using-probability-matrices)

Any clear resources also will be helpful

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site!. Could you please provide a bit more information on the investigaion? It is difficult to understand question.

Comment: Thank you.. this is a course I'm taking on Bioinformatics, with no prior knowledge in Biology or Genes. So There is a concept of searching Motif in a DNA Strings using Probability Matrices... And I have added the link of the algorithm being used for it. I assumed it is common in Bioinformatics to study this algorithm.

Comment: Here is the course link - https://stepik.org/lesson/23066/step/6?unit=6799